# Comparison of complete null column with a string in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have to include an extra line of code because of this peculiar behavior.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN,1,'2'],[np.nan,3,np.NaN]])
df1[0]=='a' # This is throwing an error
df1[0]==2 # This is returning a series
```

Comment: What is your pandas version. Mine (1.0.3) still worked for df1[0]=="a" but with a warning: `FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.
When i run :

```
df1[0]=='a'
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
```

Pls check your pandas version.

Comment: version is 0.23.0

Comment: Use pandas version >1.0.0